# Primefaces Drag Documents To Folder Structure

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to implement some drag/drop behaviour in a Primefaces application, such that you have a p:datatable of records and a p:tree which represents a folder structure. Ideally I would like to be able to drag documents from the table into individual folders in the tree, but I'm struggling to work out how you'd do that.

From what I can see the tree doesn't support other non-tree components dropping themselves into the tree nodes, or at least I can't see anything indicating you can do this.

Is this functionality not possible with Primefaces or can somebody point me in the right direction of where to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok well I managed to modify one of the custom examples from the Primefaces showcase to get the functionality I wanted, the key elements shown below:

XHTML column definition (image in column gets dragged to folder):

```
<pf:column headerText="#{bundle['column-header']}">
    <span id="document_#{message.id}">
        <pf:graphicImage value="/svg/document.svg" styleClass="datatable-layout">
            <pf:draggable revert="true" helper="clone" />
        </pf:graphicImage>
    </span>
</pf:column>
```

Tree representing folder structure (the draggable/droppable attributes are not related to the specific functionality in this thread):

```
<pf:tree value="#{backingBean.folderRoot}" var="node" droppable="true" draggable="true">
    <pf:treeNode>
        <h:outputText value="#{node}"/>
    </pf:treeNode>
</pf:tree>
```

JavaScript to make each tree node droppable:

```
$('.ui-treenode-label').droppable({
    activeClass: 'ui-state-active',
    hoverClass: 'ui-state-highlight',
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        var folderName = $(this).text();
        var spanId = document.getElementById(ui.draggable[0].id).parentNode.id;

        //span Id is of format document_{documentId}, so we need to discard the characters before the id
        var documentId = spanId.substring(spanId.indexOf("_")+1, spanId.length);

        tableToTree([
             {name: 'folderName', value:  folderName}
            ,{name: 'documentId', value: documentId}
        ]);
    }

 });
```

Remote "tableToTree" command referenced in the above javascript:

```
<pf:remoteCommand name="tableToTree" actionListener="#{backingBean.tableToTree}" 
                update="documentTable"/>
```

Finally method in backing bean reads the folder name and document id, from which it can update the model accordingly:

```
public void tableToTree() {
    Map<String,String> params = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();

    System.out.println("folderName=" + params.get("folderName"));
    System.out.println("messageId=" + params.get("messageId"));
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Solution works well in a way. It will only work one time in my dialog unless I close dialog and reopen it. Why though? Additionally, what should I do if I want to get tree node's id instead of text?